# MVC 4 - Building a Helper that accesses ViewData

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to build a helper which can execute this logic:

```
if (ViewData.ModelState[""] != null && ViewData.ModelState[""].Errors.Any())
{
    <div class="note note-danger">
        <h4 class="block">Errors</h4>
        <p>@Html.ValidationSummary()</p>
    </div>
}
```

It would need access to the **ViewData** and the **Html.ValidationSummary**

Do these need to be sent into the Helper, of can the Helper access them in some way by some base class?

My Helper:

```
public static class ValidationSummaryHelper
{
    public static HtmlString Summary(???)
    { }}
```

Comment: Is that a Razor helper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same in C#

```
public static class ValidationExtensions
{
        public static MvcHtmlString AddCustomValidationSummary(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
        {
            string result = "";

            if (htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState[""] != null && htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState[""].Errors.Any())
            {
                result = "<div class='note note-danger'><h4 class='block'>Errors</h4><p>" + htmlHelper.ValidationSummary().ToString() + "</p></div>";
            }

            return new MvcHtmlString(result);
        }
}
```

Comment: People may wonder why did I post this and decide downvote. Just FYI I thought the differences with the main question; the method parameters, was crucially different in C# compared to VB.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the syntax for it in C#, but in VB it would look like this:

```
<Extension>
Public Function AddCustomValidationSummary(htmlHelper As HtmlHelper) As MvcHtmlString
    Dim result As String = String.Empty

    If (htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState("") Is Nothing) AndAlso (htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState("").Errors.Any()) Then
        result = "<div class='note note-danger'><h4 class='block'>Errors</h4><p>" & htmlHelper.ValidationSummary().ToString() & "</p></div>"
    End If

    Return New MvcHtmlString(result)
End Function
```

Use it like:

```
@Html.AddCustomValidationSummary()
```